# Leaflet javascript in popup

Tags: javascript, leaflet, popup

Can JavaScript be included in a leaflet popup?

We have modified this  [example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start-example.html)

To this :-

```
var this_marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(mymap).bindPopup(
 '<div style="color: red">Hello<br>world<script>console.log("testing");
  </script></div>').openPopup();
```

This gives an error.

In our application we see the correctly formed HTML with script tags but the JavaScript does not run.

Comment: It would help if you put up a minimal code example in jsFiddle or similar.

Comment: This post seems similar to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698975/click-link-inside-leaflet-popup-and-do-javascript

Comment: Do you want to execute code right after the popup has been opened?

Answer (score 1):

Your code above works great without the `<script>` tag once its removed, like so:

```
var this_marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(mymap).bindPopup
('<div style="color: red">Hello<br>world</div>').openPopup();
```

If you are trying to add in additional JavaScript functionality to the popup when its open you could use a selector such as:

```
mymap.on('popupopen', function() {
    console.log(testing);    
});
```